# How to find the next value produced by nextval without advancing the sequence?

Tags: postgresql

I have an app which does have a maintenance menu (which is of course used in only very rare cases). In this menu I also display the next number that a certain sequence will generate next and give the user an option to reset the sequence.

I use the following query to show the next number:

```sql
select case when last_value is not null then last_value+increment_by else start_value end
from pg_sequences
where sequencename = 'my_sequence'
```

And if the user changes the sequence I run:

```sql
alter sequence my_sequence restart with $NEW_NUMBER
```

This usually works EXCEPT right after resetting the sequence with the query above and before any new number was pulled from the sequence. The my query to find out what the next number would be shows "1" which is not necessarily correct.

**What can I do to reliably determine the next number that `nextval` would produce if called without actually calling `nextval` (to not actually alter the sequence)?**

Comment: Why is 1 not necessarily correct?

Comment: @Bergi: If $NEW_NUMBER was a different number than 1, then 1 is not correct as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) instead of `alter sequence...`, e.g.

```
select setval('my_sequence', 110)
```

The last sequence value written to disk (`last_value` of `pg_sequences`) can be set only by nontransactional functions `nextval()` and `setval()`. After the sequence is restarted with `alter sequence ...` the last value is not saved until it is actually used by `nextval()` or set by `setval()`. This is because `alter sequence ...` may be rolled back.

Comment: Because of "*In contrast to a `setval` call, a `RESTART` operation on a sequence is transactional and blocks concurrent transactions from obtaining numbers from the same sequence. If that's not the desired mode of operation, `setval` should be used.*"?

Comment: @Bergi - I have added a short explanation.